# WolframAlpha queries unevaluated despite internet connectivity?

Tags: wolfram-alpha-queries

`WolframAlpha` is a built-in symbol in MMA8, yet expressions with `WolframAlpha` and the equal sign operator remains unevaluated despite the internet connection.

```
WolframAlpha["2+1"]

(* WolframAlpha["2+1"] *) 

= heart disease risk 50yo male

(* AlphaIntegration`ExtrusionEvaluate["heart disease risk 50yo male", TextForm] *) 

?AlphaIntegration

(* Information::notfound: Symbol AlphaIntegration not found. >> *)
```

?

Comment: I typed in `= heart disease....` but I received an answer (5.4%).  Same thing happens to me sometimes, too.  I usually wait a couple minutes then everything works fine.  I suspect it's not MMA's fault.

Comment: `AlphaIntegration` isn't a symbol, it's a *context* and `ExtrusionEvaluate` is one of the symbols in that context buried there since it's meant for internal use.

Comment: @MarkMcClure, what's the diff symbol v. context - the point is it doesn't work

Comment: @alancalvitti You typed `?AlphaIntegration`, evidently expecting it to work. I was simply trying to provide an explanation as to why it doesn't. Your overall problem is pretty clearly an anomaly or bug specific to your system; as VF1 suggests, I'd recommend waiting and trying again later. Or perhaps at a different location, or perhaps even reinstalling eventually.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall, a corporate or university proxy?

Comment: W|A queries are limited to about 100 or so per day (limit changes depending on your license). You might have hit the cap for the day.

Comment: What happens if you go to Edit -> Preferences -> Internet Connectivity -> Test Internet Connectivity?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I'm not behind a firewall.

Comment: @rm-rf, I've not tried any W|A queries at all, and I have a premium MMA license as well.

Comment: If the WolframAlpha function is not returning even an error message, then there something wrong with your current installation. You should consider resetting your copy of Mathematica: http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3274

Comment: If the problem were that it couldn't access the internet or that it had reached the quota of Wolfram|Alpha usage, then you would see an error message. The fact that it gives back a random internal function most likely means that your configuration is doing something bad.

Comment: @Renan, connectivity test ok (using pacletserver.wolfram.com)

Comment: Check Preference -> Internet Connectivity -> Wolfram|Alpha Settings, maybe?

Comment: What's the downvote about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a similar problem. I was able to resolve it by having MMA recreate configuration files under `$BaseDirectory` and `$UserBaseDirectory`. There is a description of the process at http://support.wolfram.com/kb/3274. It is important that you backup any of your own files in these directories prior to resetting the configuration. I can't guarantee this will fix your problem, but it's worth a try.

Since I'm not sure if this directly answers the OP's problem, I wanted to make this a comment rather than an answer, but I don't have those privileges.

Comment: We'll leave this here for now. Searke also commented with the same support article, but the OP hasn't responded yet. If they respond and it turns out this didn't work, I'll migrate it to a comment, otherwise it can stay :)

Answer (score 0):

For reference, you'd expect to see this:

[image: screen grab]